# Webpack generate css file for each import

Tags: css, typescript, webpack, sass

Im using webpack and this to compile scss files:

```
{
  test: /\.scss$/i,
  use: [
    // Creates css files
    {
      loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
      options: {
        esModule: true,
      },
    },
    "@teamsupercell/typings-for-css-modules-loader",
    // Translates CSS into CommonJS
    {
      loader: 'css-loader',
      options: {
        modules: true
      }
    },
    // Compiles Sass to CSS
    'sass-loader',
  ],
},
```

This is generating only one CSS file called main. I want to generate a CSS file for each SCSS file in my source so I can implement lazy loading of CSS.
I need a way to generate them individually and also generate the JavaScript to download them from the server when required.

Is this possible with the plugins that exist today?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to generate a CSS file for each SCSS file in my source so I can
>   implement lazy loading of CSS.

With this requirement, you don't need webpack. [node-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass) package is enough for you.

In the `package.json` file, you configure the `scripts` like this:

```
{
    "name": "your_project_name",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "node-sass": "^4.13.1"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "sass": "node-sass -w scss_folder -o css_folder --output-style compressed"
    }
}
```

Explanation:

`sass`: This is your command name

`node-sass`, `-w`, `-o`, `--output-style`, `compressed`: You can find their explanations via the link above.

Your project structure looks like:

```
Your_project
|
|_ css_folder
|
|_ scss_folder
|
|___ file01.scss
|
|___ file02.scss
|
|_ package.json
```

In your project, open command prompt (or Terminal on Mac) and type:

```
npm run sass
```

When it's ready to listen, you can try to create new scss file inside `scss_folder`. When you hit `ctrl+s` (or `command+s` on Mac), a new file with the same name will be generated in the folder `css_folder`, and the extension of the new file is `.css`. It's also compressed.